# Return min value for subgroups of grouped data

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

Rows are grouped by the variables **grp1, grp2, grp3**.
For each value of **varD** in the table below, I need to return the minimum value of **varA** from the minimum of all values of **VarC** that are >= **varD**? The returned value is stored in the column **varX**

On a given row, the particular **varC** and **varD** are not pairs. Rather **varD** needs to be compared to all **varC** when calculating the minimum **varC** greater than **varD**.

**varA**, **varB** and **varC** values are paired, with **varC** being the cumulative sum of **varB**.

```
grp1   grp2(POSIXct)        grp3  varA  varB  varC  varD  
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30   -100  1661  1661   280
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30      0     0  1661   560
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     57   720  2381   840
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     59     0  2381  1120
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     70     0  2381  1400
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     77     0  2381  1680
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     91    80  2461  1960
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     93     0  2461  2240
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     95     0  2461  2520
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     99   340  2801  2800
```

The expected results for a group should be:

```
grp1   grp2(POSIXct)        grp3  varA  varB  varC  varD  varX
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30   -100  1661  1661   280  -100
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30      0     0  1661   560  -100
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     57   720  2381   840  -100  
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     59     0  2381  1120  -100
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     70     0  2381  1400  -100
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     77     0  2381  1680    57
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     91    80  2461  1960    57
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     93     0  2461  2240    57
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     95     0  2461  2520    99
A      02/02/2019 05:30:00  -30     99   340  2801  2800    99
```

For varD:

- 1661 is the min **varC** >= 280 - 1400, so **varX** is -100 (min **varA** where **varC** == 1661)
- 2381 is the min **varC** >= 1680 - 2240, so **varX** is 57 (min **varA** where **varC** == 2381)
- 2801 is the min **varC** >= 2520 - 2800, so **varX** is 99 (min **varA** where **varC** == 2801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the min by groups first then use a rolling join to look the nearest min:

```
agg <- DT[, min(varA), by=.(grp1, grp2, grp3, varC)]

DT[, newvar :=
    agg[DT, on=c("grp1", "grp2", "grp3", varC="varD"), roll=-Inf]$V1
]
```

output:

```
    grp1                grp2 grp3 varA varB varC varD newvar
 1:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30 -100 1661 1661  280   -100
 2:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30    0    0 1661  560   -100
 3:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30   57  720 2381  840   -100
 4:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30   59    0 2381 1120   -100
 5:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30   70    0 2381 1400   -100
 6:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30   77    0 2381 1680     57
 7:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30   91   80 2461 1960     57
 8:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30   93    0 2461 2240     57
 9:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30   95    0 2461 2520     99
10:    A 02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30   99  340 2801 2800     99
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("grp1   grp2        grp3  varA  varB  varC  varD  
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30   -100  1661  1661   280
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30      0     0  1661   560
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30     57   720  2381   840
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30     59     0  2381  1120
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30     70     0  2381  1400
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30     77     0  2381  1680
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30     91    80  2461  1960
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30     93     0  2461  2240
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30     95     0  2461  2520
A      02/02/2019T05:30:00  -30     99   340  2801  2800")
```

Comment: This code produces the correct solution for the sample data, however, it is taking a long time to execute for my data of 4 million rows and I have yet to see the output.  Is there anything at all I could do to improve the performance of this code?

Comment: added a rolling join method. should be faster

Comment: I tried adding mult="first" and tested with a smaller dataset.  It took 1 minute to complete 10k rows of data, so my actual data set would take 6 hrs, 40 mins.  Since I actually have several datasets of 4 million+ rows, it's just not feasible yet.  Thank you for your continuing help

Comment: The rolling method is lightning fast, 4 million rows in less than 1 second.  This code is correct and feasible